# Create an array/json from columns excluding NULL values in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a sample with 6 possible phone numbers and I need to create an array or json that has them all, excluding duplicates and NULLs.

My sample is something like this:

```
WITH material as(
SELECT 619883407 as phone_1,
CAST(null AS INT64) as phone_2,
CAST(null AS INT64)  as phone_3,
CAST(null AS INT64) as phone_4,
69883407 as phone_5,
688234 as phone_6)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a IGNORE NULLS) as phones
 FROM material CROSS JOIN UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(TO_JSON_STRING([phone_1,phone_2,phone_3,phone_4,phone_5,phone_6]))) a
```

I am happy with my result, but I would need to exclude NULL values. For some reason, adding 'IGNORE NULLS' into the array_agg is not working. Any idea why would this happen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any idea why would this happen?

when you do to_json_string - all `null`s becomes strings `'null'`s

Use below instead

```
select array_agg(a) as phones
from material, 
unnest(json_extract_array(to_json_string([phone_1,phone_2,phone_3,phone_4,phone_5,phone_6]))) a
where a != 'null'
```

with output

[image]